# Is it possible to implement an IMAP push client in iOS?

Tags: ios

Would it be possible for me to implement a client that is capable of receiving IMAP push messages, without the awareness of the user (i.e. they are not displayed in an inbox etc.)

Comment: when you say IMAP push messages, do you mean sending out push notification to the user upon email arrival?

Comment: No, sending an email from a server to a client app. Such that the client app directly receives the email. (Not all emails, just specific emails pushed from a particular server under my control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create a job (corn) to check for emails every few often and send a push message (apns) to the user (using your app) with the email message attached as body.

Comment: But no way without the user knowing about it though?

Comment: Well... bare minimum you need to have an app that your user will install and grant access to push notifications.

Comment: >> "and send a push message (apns) to the user (using your app) with the email message attached as body." However push notifications are limited to a fairly small size and and not supposed to be used to deliver a payload to the device according to Apple documentation.

Comment: Yes... I believe there is a 256k limit on the payload.

Comment: 256 bytes, not 256 kilobytes. For this sort of application, push notifications are to alert a user and an app that something new needs to be downloaded. They don't contain the thing itself.